# Whole album track listing

Tags: iphone, ios, music.app

Before the update to 8.4, when I was listening to a song, there was a button in the upper right where it would bring up the whole album that track was on so you could listen to other songs on that album (for example, if I was listening to all songs on shuffle and I heard a song and wanted to see or listen to other songs on that album).  After the update, I can't find that option.  Help/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Tap on the three dots on the bottom right corner, it will pop-up a menu;

[image: three dot menu music app iOS 8.4]

Tap on the title bar on the top of the menu (in this example, the bar that says "Dam That River" and has the Album title and artwork.
This will bring you to a second screen, with some of the tracks, more albums from the same artist.

[image: album, artist]

Tap on "Show complete album"

[image: full album music app iOS 8.4]